# tikz: wonky spacing even with "on grid"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm a newbie making a simple flow diagram using relative positioning and `on grid`. My diagram is simple, so I expected everything to line up easily. But I'm getting this:

[image: wonky example]

I'm trying to draw arrows from the right-most nodes to some invisible placeholder nodes on the right margin (using `[coordinate]`), and I'm lining those up relative to the center line. But something is wonky.

Am I missing something basic? My code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {draw,font=\ttfamily\footnotesize, inner sep = 1pt}, on grid]

  % nodes on the main line + coordinate placeholders
  \node [circle] (1) {1};
  \node [circle, right=10mm of 1] (2) {2};
  \node [coordinate, right=10mm of 2] (3g) { };
  \node [circle, right=10mm of 3g] (6) {6};
  \node [coordinate, right=10mm of 6] (7g) { };
  \node [coordinate, right=10mm of 7g] (8g) { };
  \node [coordinate, right=10mm of 8g] (9g) { };

  % other nodes
  \node [circle, below=1cm of 3g] (3) {3};
  \node [circle, below=1cm of 7g] (7) {7};
  \node [circle, above=1cm of 8g] (8) {8};
  \node [circle, below=2cm of 9g] (9) {9};

  % right edge coordinate placeholders
  \node [coordinate, right=10mm of 9g] (edge) { };    
  \node [coordinate, above=1cm of edge] (edge_above) { };     
  \node [coordinate, below=1cm of edge] (edge_below1) { };     
  \node [coordinate, below=2cm of edge] (edge_below2) { };     

  % paths
  \path[draw]
        (1) -- (2)
        (2) -- (6)
        (2) |- (3)
        (3) -- (7)
        (7) |- (9)
        (6) |- (8);       

  % right arrows
  \path[draw, ->]    (8) -> (edge_above);
  \path[draw, ->]    (6) -> (edge);
  \path[draw, ->]    (7) -> (edge_below1);
  \path[draw, ->]    (9) -> (edge_below2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose there could be some improvements to your scheme, but to fix your problem, here's the solution: delete the coordinates, and rewrite your last arrows like this:

```
\draw[->] (8) -- ++ (2.5,0) coordinate (eight);
\draw[->] (6) -- (6-|eight);
\draw[->] (7) -- (7-|eight);
\draw[->] (9) -- (9-|eight);
```

Basically, the first arrow (top one), goes on for `2.5cm` and establishes a coordinate `eight` at that point. Then, using the TikZ operator `-|` we can draw arrows from the other nodes that go on, horizontally (`-`) until they reach the same vertical position of `eight` (`|`) and there, they stop.

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explaining that in a way that helps me understand how to use relative positioning properly! I see what you mean by "improvements to your scheme..." But shouldn't the original method still work in theory?

Comment: @gogurt Not really. The only straight one you had was the line starting from `6` and it was the only one that said `right=10mm of 9g`. The others were placed using this one, with `above` or `below`. But even if the measurement was right, you weren't taking into account the sizes related to the nodes: text height, inner and outer sep...

Comment: OK, I see. I'll spend some more time with the manual. Thanks again.

Comment: @gogurt Try this, set the node options like `inner sep=0, outer sep=0, minimum size=5mm`. Now that circle is exactly `5mm` big.  That means that its "center" is `2.5mm`. Then you can establish the coordinate like `above=1.25cm of edge`. Now the line will be straight. But this calculation renders Latex pointless, because the good thing is to have the code do its calculations for you. :)